threejs HDR does not work in three dimensions

I used RGBEloader to load an HDR file.
Wanted it to work three-dimensionally, but it doesn't.
Spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem, but it remains unresolved.
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! three */ "./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js");
/* harmony import */ var three_examples_jsm_controls_OrbitControls_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js */ "./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js");
/* harmony import */ var three_examples_jsm_loaders_RGBELoader_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! three/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js */ "./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js");







let renderer, scene, camera, controls;

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

function init() {




  renderer = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["WebGLRenderer"]({canvas:canvas, antialias : true});
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; 
  renderer.shadowMap.type = three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["VSMShadowMap"]; 

  // scene
  scene = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["Scene"]();
  new three_examples_jsm_loaders_RGBELoader_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["RGBELoader"]()
  .load('../public/hdr/blue_photo_studio_8k.hdr', function (texture) 
  { texture.mapping = three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["EquirectangularReflectionMapping"];
    scene.background = texture;
    scene.environment = texture;});


  // camera
  camera = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["PerspectiveCamera"]();
  camera.fov=32;
  camera.position.set(0,0,10);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 
  


  //orbit

  controls = new three_examples_jsm_controls_OrbitControls_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["OrbitControls"](camera,canvas);

  //light
  const Dlight = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["DirectionalLight"](0xffffff,0.75);
  Dlight.position.set(2,2,2);
  Dlight.castShadow = true;
  Dlight.shadow.blursample =30;
  Dlight.shadow.radius = 12;
  scene.add(Dlight);

  const Hlight = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["HemisphereLight"](0xffffff,0x000000,0.25);
  scene.add(Hlight);

  //매쉬

  const Mat01 = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["MeshStandardMaterial"]();
  const geo01 = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["SphereGeometry"](1,24,24);
  const obj01 = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["Mesh"](geo01,Mat01);
  obj01.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(obj01); 

  //floor

  const FloorGO01 = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["PlaneGeometry"](10,10);
  const Floor01 = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["Mesh"](FloorGO01,Mat01);
  Floor01.position.set(0,-1,0);
  Floor01.rotation.set(Math.PI *-0.5,0,0); //플레인은 안쪽면만 빛이 받도록 설계 되어 있음
  Floor01.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(Floor01);

  render();

}
function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  render();

}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  controls.update();

  
}

init();

//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/index-shadow.js?

I used the HDR code released by THREEjs, but the webpage came out white. I used the codes on the Internet, but they still don't work.

You seem to have posted production code instead of source code. Check in your console if you see any error?
